# What is best way to create zip file and save to Documents in iOS

Tags: ios, zip

I want to zip my documents files of my iOS app. How to do that?

Comment: There's this nifty tool called Google, ever heard of it? You like, put words in, and it like, finds stuff on the Internet, like it searches for it or something.

Comment: thanks for repy @JonathonReinhart.
I have already tried with SSZipArchive. It is a third party library. But the issue is if the size more than 40 MB. It's taking long time to Archive. And i have the requirement to unarchive also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

path for documents:

```
NSString* _path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]
```

array with file names at `_path` folder

```
NSError* _error;
NSArray* _fileNames = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:_path error:&_error]
```

for zipping try to use ZipZap:
https://github.com/pixelglow/zipzap

40mb - is small file for this =)